# How to browse the Ubuntu Server Guide https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ in PURE english from german computer and locale

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I prefer to read computer documentation in english - I have switched Firefox locale off, but still get a weird english/german mixture. I do not want to download the english pdf to this computer.

Answer (score 2):

How did you switch Firefox locale off?

If you in Firefox select **Edit -> Preferences -> Content -> Languages** and no language is selected (or English is the preferred language), the English versions of the pages should be delivered to your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can download the full English PDF https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/serverguide.pdf